# How can I fix the "incompatible data" issue when flashing Cyanogenmod onto my Xperia Z3 Compact?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, sony-xperia-z3-compact

I have a Sony Xperia Z3 Compact and I am trying to install Cyanogenmod 12.1.

I followed [the guide](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_z3c) on the Cyanogenmod Wiki for my device.

The process went smoothly initially but it fails at 40-50% completion with the message: "Install failed. Can't install this package on top of incompatible data.....E:Failed to install /sideload/package.zip..."

I've tried:

- Performing a factory reset
- Flashing an older version of Cyanogenmod

But I receive the same message when I try to flash.

When I restart the phone, it hangs indefinitely on the Sony loading screen and doesn't boot.

**How can I resolve this issue and successfully flash Cyanogenmod?**

EDIT:

I installed TWRP 3.0.2.1 and it start to reboot the phone in loop, but I manage to install 3.0.2.0 version. I was trying this time to install from usb memory, but it faild to error 7: 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx_77SKdWXozZ1NVUDIwOEFSZGM

I manage to get terminal open and I found out that I have linux version 3.4.0-cm-g28a6663

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know should I delete this message or answer to it, but I got it solved. I had to install elder version of CM12.1(20160918) and I got it to install with TWRP( Which is pretty nice bootloader). Then in the android I just updated the software to newer one and it works now.

Comment: Just accept this answer yourself - it will serve as reference to others later, which is what we answer for.

Answer (score 3):

Usually just wiping /data from the recovery and/or installing the package again *immediately* after first failure should get you through.

However if it doesn't, then you might want to ditch Cyanogen Recovery (that comes with the boot.img you flashed) and use TWRP. Find some [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/z3-compact/development) at XDA-Developers - basically any one that integrates TWRP should work, because you will be substituting it with CM's boot.img later when flashing, but it's advised that you choose one that's built for the same Android version you were on before flashing.

This sounds a bit hard to swallow and it is, but it's essential flashing skills and you will need it. With TWRP you can also put the package in internal storage and flash it from there, instead of relying on your PC to do a sideload.

Comment: I install the TWRP. The newest version reboot it self every 5s, but on olderversion (3.0.2.0) works. I try to install it again from usb memory, but same result: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bx_77SKdWXozZ1NVUDIwOEFSZGM Any ideas?